# why cursor.fetchone() or cursor.fetchall() not returning/reading data?

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am learning python and i am following [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-web-app-from-scratch-using-python-flask-and-mysql-part-2--cms-22999) tutorial. i have completed part one and now i am doing the second one. I have git repo for the same [here](https://github.com/gschauhan/flask). Currently i am stuck at this weird problem. i am trying to get data from mysql using stored procedure. i am getting data in cursor but when i call fetchall or fetchone i get no data.

`con = mysql.connect()
        cursor = con.cursor()
        cursor.callproc('sp_validateLogin',(_username,)) 
        data = cursor.fetchone() #tried fetchall here, bit no data in "data" vriable`

here is the screenshot of data fetched in cursor. [image]

so everytime code jumps to else, which should go to if. how to overcome this?

Dev environment: Win10, VS2013 with PTVS, Python v 2.7

i have gone thru 
  [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchall.html), [this](http://thepythonguru.com/fetching-records-using-fetchone-and-fetchmany/) and so many like those on internet.

Comment: Please read the description for a tag before applying it to your question. The [tag:git] tag is for questions about Git usage and workflows, not programming questions that happen to involve a Git repo. (I've [edited](//stackoverflow.com/help/editing) your question to remove it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after lots of searching and experimenting this code works.

```
data = cursor._rows
```

here i can access data fetched from mysql into the cursor. still unable to work with .fetchall() or .fetchone()